# How to load report file in the printing control? - DevExpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I created report(XtraReport) and i drag reporting tool `PrintBarManager` or `PrintControl` to form. Now I need to load that report to that PrintControl. How to load ? Help me.
I tried this code but showing error - `Object reference is not set to instance of object`

```
var test = new XtraReport1();
printControl1.Container.Add(test);  // Object reference not set to instance of object
test.ShowPreview();
```

I tried this code but it showing - `Best overloaded method match.....`

```
var test = new XtraReport1();
printControl1.Controls.Add(test);  // Best overloaded method, invalid arguments
test.ShowPreview();
```

How to load my report to PrintControl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
//Set the printing system
printControl.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;
//Create and build your report
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1(); 
report.CreateDocument();
```

P.S. Take a look at [How to: Add a Print Preview to a Windows Forms Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2668) guidance.